# Approving and Declining requests from user, Django/Python

Tags: python, django

Am going to ask for forgiveness in advance because for this specific question i have not written out any code. It is so because i have not figured out how i can do it.

Am trying to develop a web app(practice new to programming) where signed up users can make requests and then line managers approve/decline( more like requesting for leave). This is going to have multiple approvers.
I have tried using Django-River but i can not seem to understand the documentation very well. Is there any other way i can do this?
I am not requesting for code, all am requesting for is to be pointed in the right direction and i figure the next steps out. Thanks

Comment: Could you use a model form created by the user and then have the other accounts check boxes on the form for approval?

Answer (score 0):

If I had the same task, I would:

1. Introduce at least two types of users (see [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/18/how-to-implement-multiple-user-types-with-django.html)) by subclassing `django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser` to custom user model with adding either bool fields (`is_student` and `is_manager`) or `user_type` field of integer choices. For example, somewhere in `models.py`:

   ```py
   class User(AbstractUser):
       USER_TYPE_CHOICES = (
           (1, 'STUDENT'),
           (2, 'MANAGER'),
       )
       user_type = PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICES, default=1)
       #...
       #or
       #...
       is_manager = BooleanField(default=False)
       is_student = BooleanField(default=True)
   ```
2. Filter API callbacks by user type, for example somewhere in `views.py`:

   ```py
   from django.http import HttpResponse
   from django.views import View
   from django.http.response import Http404

   class SomeView(View):
       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           if not request.user.user_type==User.USER_TYPE_CHOICES[1][0]:
               raise Http404
           #coutinue your request processing
       #...
       #or
       #...
       def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           if not request.user.is_manager:
               raise Http404
           #coutinue your request processing
   ```
3. The least features (model of students requests to approve by managers, and their front pages) are well-described by any basic django tutorial, and can be implemented on starndad django model-view-form architecture.